# When receiving a file, is it better to rename the temp file in the 'finish' or in the 'close' event?

Tags: node.js

I am concerned about sporadic timing failures.

I see lots of code samples (some using pipe, I am not) that do nothing in the 'close' event. Is it an artifact of Linux OS that allows renaming a file while it is still open during the 'finish' event, or is the file actually already closed?

I also see some samples call close() in the 'finish' event. Is that required if you use the 'close' event? I've read that 'close' is not always issued somewhere.

Current code:
(Node 8.11.1 and express 4.17.1 are currently installed.)

```
let fstream = fs.createWriteStream(tempFile);
fstream.on('finish', () => {
    ...
    fs.renameSync(tempFile, realFile);
    ...
});
request.on('data', chunk => {
    fstream.write(chunk)
    ... some chunk examination here ...
});
request.on('end', () => {
    fstream.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Close`

From the docs:

> The 'close' event is emitted when the stream and any of its underlying resources (a file descriptor, for example) have been closed

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_close

And yes, it's a feature of Linux https://askubuntu.com/questions/347371/is-it-100-safe-to-rename-a-file-while-its-being-written

Comment: Thanks. I found to documentation and examples confusing. It seems like many of the examples (including in node.js's own docs) might only work for Linux, and not Windows, and the file is not really ready at the finish event.
"A Writable stream will always emit the 'close' event if it is created with the emitClose option" from the nodejs.org link above (v12.10.0) suggests that the option should be included since they don't specify when close wouldn't be issued.

Comment: Version v8.16.1 (currently distributed and in use) docs make no mention of an option but make a similar statement about close not always being issued.
fstream.on('finish', () => { fstream.close(); }
seems it might be required.

Comment: @Codemeister v8 docs: `Not all Writable streams will emit the 'close' event`, but in v10/v12 it's already `A Writable stream will always emit the 'close' event if it is created with the emitClose option.`  So it looks like `emitClose` option guarantees that `close` will be emitted.  It looks like it was introduced in v10.

Comment: @Codemeister `emitClose` first appeared in v10 https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/5e3f51648ed5de36b01d53bde13fb6fb7b965667  Looks like in v8 `close` is not guaranteed to be emitted due to the absence of `emitClose` option.